# How to move a UIButton and UIImageView from One place to Another in iphone?

Tags: iphone

How to move a `UIButton` and `UImageView` from one place to another automatically when i clicking a button. I'm also created a `UIButton` and `UIImageView` programmatically within scrollview. But i want when i clicking the button the another `UIImage` and also a button move to specified place.

Here is my code

```
if (i==0)
{
    bgImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,30+x,100,100)];
    bgImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:bgImage];
    [scrollview addSubview:bgImage];

    myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(120, 65+x, 70, 30); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
    [myButton setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
    [scrollview addSubview:myButton];
    x=x+100;
}
if (i==1) 
{
    bgImage1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,30+x,100,100)];
    bgImage1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone.png"];
    [self.view addSubview:bgImage1];
    [scrollview addSubview:bgImage1];

    UIButton *myButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton1.frame = CGRectMake(120, 65+x, 70, 30); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
    [myButton1 setTitle:@"Delete" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked1) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton1];
    [scrollview addSubview:myButton1];
    x=x+100;
}

- (void)buttonClicked1
{
    [bgImage removeFromSuperview];
    [bgImage release];
    bgImage=nil;
    myButton.enabled=NO;
    myButton.hidden=YES;
}
```

When i clicking `buttonclicked1` button the `bgImage` and `myButton` is removed its place and i want `bgImage1` and `myButton1` is moved to these place without any modification.

How to do this. Anybody give me the code pls. I cant move it. How to do this. Pls help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the frame in the button click.Do this in - (void)buttonClicked1 method

```
bgImage1.frame=CGRectMake(20,30+x,100,100);
myButton1.frame = CGRectMake(120, 65+x, 70, 30);
```

or

```
- (void)buttonClicked1
{
bgImage1.frame=bgImage.frame;
    myButton1.frame = myButton.frame;
[bgImage removeFromSuperview];
[bgImage release];
bgImage=nil;
    myButton.enabled=NO;
myButton.hidden=YES;
}
```